# Delete rows that consists of strings

Tags: regex, r

I have a column that should consist of numbers only but there are characters or other symbols in there as well. R sees the feature Housenumber as a character.

For instance:

```
Housenumber 
1
14
5
at5
53.!
boat
```

I was wondering what kind of function I could write to identify the rows that do not consist of numbers only and to delete those?

```
Housenumber 
1
14
5
```

Comment: Maybe `as.numeric(myData$Housenumber)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[length(grep("[^[:digit:]]", df$Housenumber, value=F)) == 0, ]
```

**Explanation:**

The regex `[^[:digit:]]` will match any *non* numeric character, e.g. the other characters and symbols which you want to strip.

The call

```
grep("[^[:digit:]]", df$Housenumber, value=F)
```

will return a vector containing the first index of your `Housenumber` column if a match is found.  So if a match isn't found, the length of this vector will be zero, and it means you want to keep that row.

In this particular case, I prefer the answer given by @akrun, but my answer also works in the general case of filtering rows using any sort of regex.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `as.numeric` which will convert the non-numeric elements to NA, and we delete those rows with `!is.na` that gives a logical index.

```
df1[!is.na(as.numeric(df1$Housenumber)),, drop= FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the values to numeric via `as.numeric`. Non-numeric values will be coerced to `NA`, so you can filter out `NA`-values in the second step.

```
Housenumber <- c(1,14,5,"at5","53.!","boat") # Create your housenumber vector

Housenumber <- as.numeric(Housenumber) # Convert it to numeric

Housenumber <- Housenumber[!is.na(Housenumber)] # Filter out the NA
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

write this function if you need it more than one time in your code:

```
numerics_of = function (x){
nums = c()
a = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x));
return (a[!is.na(a)])
}
```

and for exmaple:

```
x = c(2,4,5,3,2,"a",2,3,4)
numerics_of(x)
```

will give this output

```
[1] 2 4 5 3 2 2 3 4
```